# how to Filter one list based on another lists field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am fetching data from database from separater tables and storing in separate variables.

this is first list

```
   var res = (from v in context.MasterValues
                       join c in context.MasterCategories on v.Category_Id equals c.Id
                       where c.Model_Key == (int)model && c.Name == tableName && v.Version_Id == version && v.Active == "Y" && c.Name.Equals("FXRates")
                       select new 
                       {
                           Id = v.Id,
                           VersionId = v.Version_Id,
                           Text1 = v.Text1,
                       }).ToList();
```

This is second list

```
        var fxview = context.MasterFXRates.Select
            (x => new
            {
                Currency_code = x.Currency_code,
                Rate = x.Rate,
                Effective_dt = x.Effective_dt
            }
            ).ToList();
```

So now How to filter Data from my second list **fxview** based on data from my first list ?
i.e. 
i need to filter data where Currency_code's data of list2 matches with  Text1 of List1 where effective_dt(datetime column) is maximum/Latest date

For Example if second lists data has

1. ABC , 100 , 2010-10-10
2. ABC , 120 , 2014-12-12
3. DEF ,700 , 2013-08-02
4. DEF ,500 ,2015-06-06

And List 1(res) has following data

1. 1 , 1 , ABC
2. 2 , 1 , DEF

So after filtering my final list must have following output

1. ABC ,120 (Since 2014-12-12 is latest date , the corresponding value is fetched and duplicate value (ABC,100) should be filtered.)

2.DEF ,500 (Since 2015-06-06 is latest date , the corresponding value is fetched and duplicate value (DEF,&00) should be filtered.)

Comment: If the lists only required to perform filtering, I suggest to perform `JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var result = from masterFxRate in masterFxRates
                     join masterValue in masterValues on masterFxRate.Currency_code equals masterValue.Text1
                     group masterFxRate by
                     new
                     {
                         masterFxRate.Currency_code
                     } into groupedRates
                     select new
                     {
                         groupedRates.Key.Currency_code,
                         Rate = groupedRates.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Effective_dt != null 
                                                              && g.Effective_dt == groupedRates.Max(c => c.Effective_dt)).Rate
                     };

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} ", item.Currency_code, item.Rate);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  fxView = fxView.OrderByDescending(x => x.effectiveDate).ToList();
  var result = new List();
 res.ForEach((x) => result.Add(fxView.First(y => x.text1 == y.currency_code)));
```

If effectiveDate is already a DateTime this should work otherwise convert it to a DateTime

```
 var fxview = context.MasterFXRates.Select
        (x => new
        {
            Currency_code = x.Currency_code,
            Rate = x.Rate,
            Effective_dt = Convert.ToDateTime(x.Effective_dt)
        }
        ).ToList();
```